# Examples of smooth and non-smooth normed spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm new in functional analysis. I have a question about smooth normed spaces.

A normed space $X$ is called smooth if for every $0\neq x\in X$, there exists a unique functional $\varphi \in X^*$ such that $\| \varphi \|=1$ and $\varphi (x)=\| x\|$.

I was wondering if someone could give me examples of smooth normed space and non-smooth normed space. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1321010/is-ell-infty-a-smooth-normed-space?rq=1) and [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3265417/a-question-on-smooth-spaces).

Comment: @Brifa Thanks a lot for the comment. I have a question: why Hilbert spaces are smooth?

Comment: By the Riesz representation theorem, any functional on a Hilbert space $H$ is of the form $\varphi=\left< -, y_\varphi\right>_H$ for some $y_\varphi \in H$, and $\| \varphi \|=\| y_\varphi \|=\sqrt{\left<y_\varphi, y_\varphi \right>_H}$. If you take $x\in H\setminus\{0\}$, then $\varphi=\left< - , \frac{x}{\| x \|}\right>_H$  is such that $\varphi(x)=\| x \|$ and $\| \varphi \|=1$. It is not hard to show that it is the only functional with this property.